# Rails do select helper for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, dictionary, model

I have Order model. But for it i need to introduce some edit. 
I need to do select list and put it in model file, for example

```
id | name
```

When i create new order i put in db as orderstatus_id for example 1.
When i see this value in admin panel i want to see name. But how to do it without any db table?
Also for example when i change in admin panel order status i see this select list...

So i need changes in model, controller, and views... but how to do what i describe below?
Also i understand that it sound like wide-question, but no, it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select helpers are designed to work with objects that are enumerable (respond to each).
Typically they are arrays of AREL result objects,  but they don't HAVE to be. you could do this:

```
<%= f.select :thing , [['Big Thing',1],['Medium Thing',2],['Huge Thing',3]] %>
```

Or you could do this:

```
config/initializers/thing.rb:
  $mythings = [['Big Thing',1],['Medium Thing',2],['Huge Thing',3]]
```

Then you could do:

```
<%= f.select :thing, $mythings %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a non-SQL database? you can use mongodb (mongoid is the gem name) [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/rails.html) is the doc.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an OrderStatus model with a `name` field. Then your Order model should declare `has_one :order_status`. You can then use `@order.order_status.name` to get the order status by name. Then your select helper will be something like:

```
select("foo", "orderstatus_id", OrderStatus.all.collect {|os| [ os.name, os.id ] })
```